# Windows Phone 8.1 crashing when creating a DB lock

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I have the following code which I use frequently with Android and iOS when creating apps. Simply, it creates a lock when inserting, creating or updating a table.

```
public class SQL
{
    readonly object dbLock = new object();
    const string DBClauseSyncOff = "PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS=OFF;";
    const string DBClauseVacuum = "VACUUM;";

    #region Setup

    public bool SetupDB()
    {
        lock (dbLock)
```

As soon as the WinPhone 8.1 app hits this lock line, an exception is thrown. As this is part of a Xam.Forms application, I call this into existence using the following

```
    public App()
    {
        App.Self = this;

        var netLanguage = DependencyService.Get<ILocalise>().GetCurrent();
        LangResources.Culture = new CultureInfo(netLanguage);

        ConnectionString = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnectionString();
        App.Self.SQLitePlatform = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetPlatform();

        DBManager = new SQL();
        DBManager.SetupDB();
```

Nothing is being called asynchronously with the two dependency services returning as their names suggest the connection and platform in use.

The calls look like this

```
public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var documents = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        var pConnectionString = System.IO.Path.Combine(documents, "preferences.db");
        var connectionString = string.Format("{0}; New=true; Version=3;PRAGMA locking_mode=NORMAL; PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL; PRAGMA cache_size=20000; PRAGMA page_size=32768; PRAGMA synchronous=off", pConnectionString);
        return connectionString;
    }
    public ISQLitePlatform GetPlatform()
    {
        return new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT();
    }
```

If I comment out the SetupDB line, the app runs as I would expect. If it is left in, the app crashes with the error that it cannot create the initial display.

Is there something I need to be doing (or not doing) in order for the DB code to work on all platforms and not just Android and iOS?

Comment: What is the exception that you get?

Comment: The exception is `System.Exception: Failed to create initial page
   at MyMobileApp.WinPhone.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)`. However, removing the DBSetup line and this exception goes which is why I think it's related to the lock

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? Or turned on the "break when thrown" option for exceptions? Those might help track it down.